# ANT war task- How to war only new /modified files

Tags: ant

How do i modify ant war task so when everytime it is called, instead of building whole application, it builds only new files or modified files. I tried to use update, duplicate attributes and they do not seem helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
modified
```

tag

```
<war ... >
  <fileset dir="${local.dir}">
    <modified>
      <param name="cache.cachefile" value="localdev.cache"/>
    </modified>
  </fileset>
</war>
```